# Can't grant all privileges on schema public to a user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, schema, privileges

I tried to give all privileges to user in order to access the table `pg_largeobject` in public schema:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO my_user ;
```

even using this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE PG_LARGEOBJECT TO my_user;
```

returns this error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

How can I give privileges to this user or I should connect to database with `postgres` which has superuser privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a superuser to grant permissions on `pg_largeobjects`.

**But you should never do that.**

There is no need to modify that system catalog directly, and doing so will jeopardize the integrity of your PostgreSQL database.

To delete a large object, use

```
SELECT lo_unlink(4711);
```

Here 4711 is the OID of the large object you want to delete.

Comment: I need to delete some large files inserted into this table

Comment: Then use `lo_unlink`, as shown in my extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only grant privileges on objects if you have been granted these privileges with GRANT option or you are granting these privileges as superuser.